# node js build problem with an error "'.' is not recognized"

Tags: node.js, npm-scripts

I am learning Node and working on a existing project which has build script as below:

```
"build": "npm run clean && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --env=production --progress --profile --colors --display-optimization-bailout"
```

I did the `npm install` as per the instruction, but the build command gives an error below:

```
$ npm run build

> npm run clean && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --env=development --progress --profile --colors --display-optimization-bailout

> rimraf build

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any idea on what I could be missing and how I can troubleshoot the problem, I am on windows pc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the path to `webpack` in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"...\"`.

For instance:

```
"build": "npm run clean && \"./node_modules/.bin/webpack\" --env=production --progress --profile --colors --display-optimization-bailout"
                           ^^                           ^^
```